# why does certain short code no longer work in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a new plugin (optimizely) on my Wordpress site. I need the new plugin and it isn't optional. However, since installing it, the shortcode on another plugin (download monitor) no longer works.

All the downloads that I had in my posts just disappeared.

the php shortcodes in my posts look like this: `[download id="2981"]`

I tried deactivating the optimizely plugin, but it doesn't make a difference. I think something got changed in the settings of wordpress??? This is my guess. The odd thing is that optimizely uses php short codes as well, so it can't be that short codes are no longer active...

Can anyone tell me where I should look?

UPDATE:
I also have Jetpack installed... which has a features called shortcodes. I just tried to insert a YouTube video in to a post using their shortcode format and it didn't work either!

UPDATE2:
Cancel previous update... other short does work fine. My bad.

Comment: Strange, I doubt WordPress itself was changed or modified, perhaps your post content was? You should verify the shortcodes' brackets didn't get escaped by viewing your post content in raw HTML mode.

Comment: nope. they seem to be there when i look at the html version of my posts.

Comment: Can you put WP into debug mode and seeing if any errors are being echoed?

Comment: I don't know how to do that... but I have a small update in the question.

Comment: As a WP Plugin author their is very little magic behind registering a shortcode, so I don't believe Optimizely's plugin broke shortcodes, especially after you disabled it. That said I'm unsure how else to help, here is a link to turning on debug in WP: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: @macguru2000 thank you for the attempt to help! your comments may yet help me get to the bottom of it. when i do i will post here. thanks again!